# Trigger to update balance after a transaction amount record has been changed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-express

Tables account and transactions

```
Account = {accNumber, balance, ...}
Transaction = {accNumber, amount, transNumber, ...}
```

Where `Transaction.accNumber references Account.accNumber`

I have managed to create trigger to update balance after `INSERT`

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Account_Balance
ON Transactions AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE account SET
        balance = ins.newBalance
    FROM (
        SELECT a.accnumber,a.balance + SUM(i.amount) AS newBalance
        FROM Account a
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.accNumber = a.accNumber
        GROUP BY a.accNumber, a.balance
    ) AS ins
    WHERE account.accnumber = ins.accnumber
END
```

Now I need to create a trigger that would change balance accordingly to transaction `AFTER UPDATE`.

Example:

```
   |accNumber | balance | ...
   |-----------------------------
   |        1 |   100   | ...

   |accNumber | amount | ...
   |-----------------------------
   |        1 |   20   | ...
```

If we UPDATE `amount` to 10, `balance` should change to 90.
How can I possibly do that?

Comment: Add `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE` to your definition?

Comment: A view (indexed if needed) would do this automatically - why bother with the complexity?

Comment: @DaleK AFTER UPDATE would still increment the balance even if the amount decreases. I guess I'd have to add the amount change to balance, only if I had an idea of how to do that (at the moment).

Comment: @SMor I'm afraid its just the part of my task.

Comment: You'd need to provide sample data and desired results if you want assistance with the logic.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't clearly illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**You should really do this in a normalized fashion, by using a view.** For better performance, you can index it.

Indexed views are subject to some restrictions, in particular:

- No outer joins or applys
- Must be schema-bound
- Grouped views need `COUNT_BIG` and can only use `SUM` as another aggregate

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.vAccountBalance
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS

SELECT
  tr.accnumber,
  SUM(tr.amount) AS balance,
  COUNT_BIG(*) AS numTransactions -- this MUST be added
FROM dbo.Transactions tr;  -- schema-qualify

GO
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_vAccountBalance ON dbo.vAccountBalance (accnumber);
```

The server will maintain this index together with other indexes, during any insert, update or delete.

---

If you *really* wanted to do this in a trigger, you can use the following

- Note how the `Account` table is only referenced once, and the difference is added, rather than self-joining again
- Note how `inserted` and `deleted` are joined together by primary key, and the difference is summed

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER TR_Account_Balance
ON Transactions AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
    RETURN;  -- early bail-out

UPDATE a  -- update the already referenced Account table
SET
    balance += ins.diffBalance
FROM Account a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      i.accnumber,
      SUM(i.amount) AS diffBalance
    FROM (
        SELECT i.transNumber, i.accnumber, i.amount
        FROM inserted i
    )
    FULL JOIN (
        SELECT d.transNumber, d.accnumber, -(d.amount)
        FROM deleted d
    ) ON i.transNumber = a.transNumber
    GROUP BY i.accNumber
) AS ins ON a.accnumber = ins.accnumber;

GO
```

You could also split this up into separate `INSERT` `UPDATE` and `DELETE` triggers, in which case you can remove the `deleted` section for the former, remove the `inserted` section for the latter, and change the `UPDATE` one to use an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `FULL JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the insert update delete via a proc that will be the best place to update the mapped table or other tables as well.
If you still want to do it in a trigger (Carefully) please compute your SUM at same table level and update the balance on main table so it'll cover update and delete as well.

**Schema:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.AccountTransaction
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Account

CREATE TABLE dbo.Account
(
    AccountNumber INT            CONSTRAINT PK_AccountId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    Balance       DECIMAL(18, 9) CONSTRAINT DF_Account_Balance DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Account
(
    Balance
)
VALUES
(
    DEFAULT -- decimal(18, 9)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.AccountTransaction
(
    AccountTransactionId INT            CONSTRAINT PK_AccountTransactionId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    AccountNumber        INT            CONSTRAINT FK_AccountTransaction_Account FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.Account (AccountNumber) NOT NULL,
    Amount               DECIMAL(18, 9) CONSTRAINT DF_AccountTransaction_Amount DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tr_AccountTransaction
ON dbo.AccountTransaction
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Inserted AS INT =
            (
                SELECT COUNT (1)
                FROM   INSERTED
            )
    DECLARE @Deleted AS INT =
            (
                SELECT COUNT (1)
                FROM   DELETED
            )

    IF @Inserted > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Account
        SET    Balance = x.NewBalance
        FROM
               (
                   SELECT   SUM (at.Amount) AS NewBalance
                   FROM     Inserted AS i
                   JOIN     dbo.AccountTransaction AS at
                       ON   at.AccountNumber = i.AccountNumber
                   GROUP BY i.AccountNumber
               ) AS x
    END

    IF @Inserted = 0
       AND @Deleted > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.Account
        SET    Balance = x.NewBalance
        FROM
               (
                   SELECT   SUM (at.Amount) AS NewBalance
                   FROM     Deleted AS d
                   JOIN     dbo.AccountTransaction AS at
                       ON   at.AccountNumber = d.AccountNumber
                   GROUP BY d.AccountNumber
               ) AS x
    END
END
GO
```

** DEBUG**

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AccountTransaction
(
    AccountNumber,
    Amount
)
SELECT a.AccountNumber,
       12.0
FROM   dbo.Account AS a

SELECT a.AccountNumber,
       a.Balance
FROM   dbo.Account AS a

UPDATE at
SET    at.Amount += 30
FROM   dbo.AccountTransaction AS at
WHERE  at.AccountTransactionId = 1

SELECT a.AccountNumber,
       a.Balance
FROM   dbo.Account AS a
 
SELECT at.AccountTransactionId,
       at.AccountNumber,
       at.Amount
FROM   dbo.AccountTransaction AS at

UPDATE at
SET    at.Amount -= 20
FROM   dbo.AccountTransaction AS at
WHERE  at.AccountTransactionId = 1

SELECT a.AccountNumber,
       a.Balance
FROM   dbo.Account AS a
 
SELECT at.AccountTransactionId,
       at.AccountNumber,
       at.Amount
FROM   dbo.AccountTransaction AS at
DELETE a
FROM   dbo.AccountTransaction AS a
WHERE  a.AccountTransactionId = 2

SELECT a.AccountNumber,
       a.Balance
FROM   dbo.Account AS a

SELECT at.AccountTransactionId,
       at.AccountNumber,
       at.Amount
FROM   dbo.AccountTransaction AS at
```

[image]

Comment: That's going to bug out on a delete or an update, you need to reference `deleted` to check for difference, and you need `Balance += x.Difference`

Comment: And your only (and trivial) update test INCREASED the balance. Try a change that DECREASES the balance.

Comment: Ya i was trying to simplify my query and pasted the wrong version my bad. Appreciate you spotting that. @Charlieface

Comment: Still wrong: for updates you need to compare both the `inserted` and `deleted`, you also need to account for difference. At this stage separate triggers is probably wiser

Comment: i had that as well and removed. we do that a lot for audit triggers but for the requirement we do not need that i guess. If there is an insert [regardless of delete] were computing the sum on all rows for that account. so it should capture the value needed. If you see my logic you can see i'm using inserted and deleted temp tables purely for account number mapping. Sum is based on all lines it finds on Main table not the inserted or deleted records