# SQL Insert Trigger how to insert the data to A+Students table if the inserted marks are a+ or A+

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER [aplusresulttrig] ON [dbo].[sturesults]
    After INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN 
    SELECT d.stuid,d.subid,d.result FROM inserted d
    if(d.result='a+' or d.result='A+')
        INSERT INTO dbo.aplusresult(stuid,subid)
        values(d.stuid,d.subid)     
    END
```

Comment: are you using `sql server` ?

Comment: yes  ms sql server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger to update balance after a transaction amount record has been changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70251202/trigger-to-update-balance-after-a-transaction-amount-record-has-been-changed) You should just use a view, an indexed one if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the right syntax :

```
CREATE TRIGGER [aplusresulttrig] ON [dbo].[sturesults]
    After INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO dbo.aplusresult(stuid,subid) 
       SELECT d.stuid,d.subid
       FROM inserted d
       WHERE d.result in ('a+','A+')  
    END
```

Comment: hey thanks works for me